# Creating a journal website

Tags: php, perl, social-media

As a project I would like to create a website that allows a user to login (create a login/password if doesn't exist) and enter some data for the day (say miles run, calories burned, situps done, etc).  The website would record this data for the user for that day and build a running log of various activities.  The user would be able to go back and edit entries.  The user could then view the history of their various activities.

I have written some perl code to handle the various analysis that I intend to do on the user-entered data.  I also can easily create a perl script to save a flat file with the user generated data appended with the data and allow editing.

But I have no clue how to get this into a web experience and unfortunately I don't even know where to start!

Any idea how I should go about doing this?  It doesn't need to be a super fancy website, just functional.  Where should I start?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/). CGI.pm is a simple Perl tool to create web pages. For more advanced tool look at [Mojolicious](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/) framework. I use [CGI::Application framework](http://cgi-app.org) but it is old and for me it is already too simple, Catalyst and Mojolicious are more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I would use WordPress or Drupal as the basic framework. In [Drupal7 you'd create a new content type](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui), in Wordpress you'd create a [new "Post Type" (new as of WP 3.0)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) for users to enter data. You'd then write code to fetch & process that data.

But you could off course just use WordPress with [the Runners Log plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/runners-log/) (and Drupal probably has a similar plugins), if you wouldn't want to do the coding ;-)